# For lightning:input can I set my own Id attribute?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am using aXe tool to do accessibility testing and it is giving me a red flag because it doesn't like the current value in the id attribute, that is set to "input-1".

Question is how, if possible do I set my own custom Id?

[image]

Comment: you cant - if my understanding is correct, those are managed by the aura framework when rendering lighning namespaced components. if a component has multiple lighing:inputs, it will add input id's input-1, input-2 and so on...

Answer (score 3):

What you see is the *Global ID*, which is rendered at run-time. You **cannot** set a *Global ID*, but only a *Local ID* (using aura:id).

For more details, refer to [**Component IDs**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm) in Lightning Components Developer Guide.

> Every component has a unique ***globalId***, which is the generated runtime-unique ID of the component instance. A global ID (1) ***is not guaranteed to be the same beyond the lifetime of a component, so it should never be relied on***. A global ID can be useful to differentiate between multiple instances of a component or for debugging purposes.